# Magento 2.2.1 Unable to save shipping information. Please check input data

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.1

Using PHP 7.x
Ubuntu 16.04
NGinx 1.10.2

After adding the product in the cart and filling out all the necessary information and clicking Next to checkout is giving me this error

Unable to save shipping information. Please check input data.

I am not able to find any solution wondering if there's some one who can assist.

Thanks[image: Unable to save shipping information. Please check input data.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the Magento logs. It appears my currency setting was change to AFN after migration process.

Solution was very simple. I change AFN to match with my default currency I.e USD & Everything started working.

Comment: there is no need to code change?

Comment: In my case, all good with the currency but still I have been facing the same issue..Do you have any possible fixes for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this issue after upgrading Magento version from 2.1.9 to 2.2.3

It happens at one of these places:

- I add the product to cart.
- On checkout page, if I click on Place Order button

So it throws below error:

```
Unable to save address. Please check input data.
```

I did following on server:
On Plesk I had to change the include_path for php from

> .:/opt/plesk/php/7.0/share/pear

to

> .:/var/www/vhosts/mysitehomedir/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library

Saved changes and then restarted apache.
Then flushed Magento Cache, and then my problem resolved.

I hope it would help you as well!

Comment: Hello, i am getting this same problem. can u tell me where to change the path?

Comment: Hello @StevenHarris, sorry for late reply.You need set this path in your plesk panel (i.e. PHP path in your hosting setting), you can explain about this setting to your hosting support, then will change the path. Hope it will be helpful for you. Thanks