# magento 2.2.3 Unable to save shipping information. Please check input data

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.3

> "Unable to save shipping information. Please check input data"

I am fetching above error on the **checkout page** in Magento **version 2.2.3**,
Anyone know what is the solution?

Comment: Please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202197/magento-2-2-1-unable-to-save-shipping-information-please-check-input-data

Comment: Given URL by you, I can't understand easily.
what's AFN?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23908#issuecomment-518875486